# Forms of integral equality

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral equality however I believe there is no closed form for the value of a that satisfies it. However i don't know how to create a sum that converges relatively fast. Here is how far i got:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(1-t^{x}\right)}{1-t}dt\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(1-t^{a}\right)}{1-t}dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-t+\ln\left(t\right)}{\left(1-t\right)\ln\left(t\right)}dt-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(1-t^{a}\right)}{1-t}dt=0$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1-t+\ln\left(t\right)}{\left(1-t\right)\ln\left(t\right)}-\frac{\left(1-t^{a}\right)}{1-t}\right)dt=0$$

Comment: *"there is no closed form for the value of x a that satisfies it."* I don't get this: are we looking for $a$ which makes the equation true?

Comment: @Raffaele yes sorry i changed the variable while making the question, I am trying to find the value of a that satisfies the equality.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1-t^x}{1-t} \, dt=H(x)$$
$H(x)$ is the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation)

$$H(n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\int _{0}^{1}{\frac {1-x^{n}}{1-x}}\,dx$$

It can be proved that $H(x)=\psi ^{(0)}(x+1)+\gamma$

where $\psi ^{(0)}$ is the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function)
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1-t^x}{1-t} \, dt= \int_0^1H_x \, dx=\gamma$$
RHS is
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1-t^a}{1-t} \, dt=H(a)$$
therefore equality is true if
$$H(a)=\gamma$$
$$\psi ^{(0)}(a+1)+\gamma =\gamma$$
$$\psi ^{(0)}(a+1)=0$$
There is no closed form for the inverse of the polygamma function, so I found an approximate value for positive $a$
$$a\approx 0.461632$$

Edit

$\psi (1)=-\gamma;\;\psi (2)=1-\gamma$

therefore there exists $a\in (0,1)$ such that $\psi^{(0)}(a+1)=0$

With Newton method, starting from $x_0=0.5$

$$
\begin{array}{l|r|r}
 n & x_n & error\\
\hline
 0 & 0.5 & 0.039035 \\
 1 & 0.460965 & 0.000666909 \\
 2 & 0.4616319 & 2\times 10^{-7} \\
 3 & 0.4616321449683 & 1.9\times 10^{-14} \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: This shows that the values of a that make the equality true are just the roots of the digamma function however what i need is a way to approximate these values

Comment: @r00r I have edited adding some detail

Comment: @r00r Have a look here http://bariskurt.com/calculating-the-inverse-of-digamma-function/